# SDL_ttf clearing all my prior and future renders

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw, sdl, sdl-ttf

I've been struggling with getting SDL and SDL_ttf to work together. My minimal reproducible case (down below) works in VC++ but for the life of me I can't get it to work in a MinGW environment.

- SDL version: 2.0.10 (latest at moment of writing)
- SDL_ttf version: 2.0.15 (latest at moment of writing)

My set up looks like this:

- Copied SDL and SDL_ttf lib and include folders to my project root.
- Set up my link and include in my Makefile like so:

```
SRC_DIR=./app/src
INC_DIR=./app/inc
OBJ_DIR=./.obj
BUILD_DIR=./build

NAME=$(BUILD_DIR)/out
all: $(NAME)

CC=gcc
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -pedantic --std=c++17 -g

# Objects to build
STNAMES=\
        main \

OBJECTS=$(patsubst %,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(STNAMES))

# Windows specific settings
ifeq ($(OS), Windows_NT)

LINK=\
     -L./SDL2/lib \
     -L./SDL2_ttf/lib \
     -lmingw32 \
     -lSDL2main \
     -lSDL2 \
     -lSDL2_ttf \
     -lstdc++ \

INCLUDE=\
        -I$(INC_DIR) \
        -I./SDL2/include \
        -I./SDL2_ttf/include \

define mkdir =
    if not exist "$(1)" mkdir "$(1)"
endef

define rmdir =
    if exist "$(1)" del /S/Q "$(1)"
endef

EXECUTABLE=$(NAME).exe

# macOS specific settings
# UNTESTED, assumes dependencies are installed with brew
else

LINK=$(shell sdl2-config --libs) -lc++
INCLUDE=\
        -I$(shell brew --prefix)/include/SDL2 \

define mkdir
    mkdir -p $(1)
endef

define rmdir =
    rm -rf $(1)
endef

EXECUTABLE=$(NAME)

endif

$(NAME): $(OBJECTS)
    @$(call mkdir,$(BUILD_DIR))
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) $(LINK)
    @$(EXECUTABLE)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    @$(call mkdir,$(OBJ_DIR))
    @$(CXX) -o $@ -c $< $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDE)

re:
    @$(call rmdir,$(OBJ_DIR))
    make
```

- Added the dlls to MinGW's `bin` folder.

Here's a minimal reproducible test case which works for me on Visual Studio, but not on MinGW:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>

void drawText(SDL_Renderer* renderer, TTF_Font* font, int x, int y, const char* text) {
    auto surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, text, SDL_Color{ 255, 255, 255, 255 });
    auto texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);

    SDL_Rect dstRect = { x, y, surface->w, surface->h };
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &dstRect);

    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("some title", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 1920, 1080, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);

    TTF_Init();

    bool running = true;
    SDL_Event event;
    auto font = TTF_OpenFont("assets/courier_prime.ttf", 36);

    while (running) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                running = false;
        }

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 25, 25, 25, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        drawText(renderer, font, 10, 10, "Test string");

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255 );
        auto rect = SDL_Rect{10, 100, 110, 200};
        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    TTF_CloseFont(font);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    TTF_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Regardless of where I place that `SDL_RenderFillRect` (before or after the drawText), the only thing I see is the text. The Rectangle is no longer visible.

I'm currently dealing with a mixed OS dev environment (mac and windows), hence why I'd like it to build on both using make.

Comment: You forgot to call `TTF_CloseFont` on the font. This will create memory leaks for every rendered frame and since you don't use `SDL_WaitEvent`, frames will be rendered as fast as your hardware allows. That doesn't seem to have to do anything with the problem, but I strongly suggest to render the text *once* before the loop, keep the texture and render that each time.

Comment: btw, do show your complete Makefile! From what you show, you don't link against OpenGL (`-lopengl32` on Windows, `-framework OpenGL` on macOS) which is required for SDL to have an accelerated renderer. On a side note, Makefiles are not a good tool to do multi-os targeting as you see from the different linking flags, you might want to have a look at CMake instead. With CMake, you can generate a VS project on Windows and an XCode project on macOS which is probably what you want rather than having to deal with MinGW on Windows.

Comment: @flyx I am well aware of the memory leaks, this is only a testing setup which isn't meant to run for more than a second to see the text rendering :)
I'll add my entire makefile to the initial post.

Comment: Well you don't link against OpenGL anywhere, I can only guess that SDL uses the software rendering fallback. This doesn't really explain your problem, but do try to add `-lopengl32` to your Windows build.

Comment: @flyx I added -lopengl32 and see no changes. It is using a heap of my GPU processing power (expected, since I render as fast as possible), so it is using my GPU regardless of linking opengl or not. https://imgur.com/kJ4T86k

Comment: @flyx you did give me the idea to test with `SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE`, which did the trick! Now it does render both the text and the square, what a strange thing. Guess I'll be running the software renderer for now. Very strange that it does work on VS though. I guess that'll remain a mystery...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it was an issue with SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED and openGL not being linked. Linking openGL did not fix the issue, however, swapping to the software renderer (SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE) did fix the rendering bug. Very strange that it does work on VS though. I guess that'll remain a mystery...

Comment: Hmm, that is probably caused by a missing `SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL` flag in your `SDL_CreateWindow` call. I just saw that it's missing.

Comment: … I totally forgot that SDL can also use Direct3D. This is probably what your code in VS was using and why it worked, but it would need additional compilation switches in MinGW. I don't know about the details, never used it.

Comment: Described behaviour very much resembles a bug with SDL2's d3d renderer that is fixed in upstream but not in 2.0.10 release (if I remember right, it first occured between 2.0.9 and 2.0.10). You can update to not-yet-released newest SDL, downgrade to previous release, or use opengl renderer.

Comment: `SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL` flag would make sense :). I'll do some more experimentation.
And good to know that it's a known bug, I'll keep an eye out for future releases.